# How to force form client-side validation in or before $.ajax()

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form and unobtrusive validations are enabled. By default in submit method client side validation gets triggered and (if you have any errors) the form looks like this:

[image]

The validation happens even before any data gets sent to the server.

Now this behavior doesn't work if you want to use $.ajax method. Client side validation doesn't work. You have to manually check all the fields in your javascript, losing all the beauty of DataAnnotations.

Is there any better solution? I could've use jquery's **submit()** but I guess it doesn't have callback like **$.ajax**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oh...

```
if (form.valid()) // do submit
```

Comment: For some reason, I get .valid() is not a function even though my client side validation is working normally :( aghhh

Comment: @Yablargo I also use this technique http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/

Comment: Ended up figuring out the issue, it was due to 2 different jquery being loaded inadvertently

Comment: oh yeah... I've been through that

Answer (score 2):

You must force the form to validate before checking if it is valid. Something like this:

```
var form = $( "#myform" );
form.validate();
if (form.valid()) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did...

```
$("#form-submit-button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Stops the form automatically submitting
    if ($("#my-form").valid()) {
        $("#my-form").submit();
    }
});
```

This also seems to be a good solution if you have say textboxes with a plugin to make those textboxes into a calendar control. Only reason I say this is because I used Zebra Datepicker with an MVC form and it would submit an invalid form if focus was on the calendar date picker. Using the below code stops this.

Comment: I had a completely different problem but your `e.preventDefault();` pointed me in the right direction... along with `$('#form').on('submit', function (e) { code });`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue Yablargo was having in that it was saying that valid is not a function, so I came up with this:

For the onclick handler of the submit button, I put this:

onclick="return $(this).closest('form').checkValidity();"