# Telerik().ScriptRegistrar() How to prevent loading jquery libraries?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

Script registrar loads jquery.validation.min.js even after

```
Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false)
```

Is there any way to tell it not to do so?

Even when I try to load exactly what I need, doing this:

```
@Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).DefaultGroup(g =>
{
    g.Add("telerik.common.min.js");
    g.Add("telerik.tabstrip.min.js");
}
```

And if for example I have a telerik grid on the page it would load all necessary scripts including grid.min, grid.editing and jquery.validate.min.

I prefer to control it myself and instead of that simply to get an error, or non-functioning elements if I forgot to define the right scripts.

If I try to use this snippet:

```
@Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).Scripts(s =>
{
    s.Add("telerik.common.min.js");
...
```

It ignores `useTelerikContentDeliveryNetwork="true"` in web.config, and searches for scripts on local server. I still want to use CDN.

**UPD:** Is there actually a way to use telerik's CDN sources but if for some reason they are down, load all the stuff from the project's server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a further update to this answer for people coming from search engines: You can now remove jQuery Validation in addtion to jQuery by using something like:

```
@Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).jQueryValidation(false)
```

Answer (score 4):

`.jQuery(false)` indeed prevents including of jquery.js only. It does not affect jquery.validate.js and was never meant to. Currently there is no way to stop the ScriptRegistrar from including jquery.validate.js when there is an editable grid in the page.

There is no built-in support for fallback when you are using the Telerik CDN. A manual workaround can be implemented though. Something like this:

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar())
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery === "undefined" || typeof $.telerik === "undefined") {
       // the CDN failed for some reason use local files
       document.write("<script src='scripts/telerik.common.min.js'><\/script>");
       document.write("<script src='scripts/telerik.grid.min.js'><\/script>");
       // etc
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey.. you are in the Telerik team.. right? Thank you guys for the great stuff. It is absolutely great!

Comment: Yes I am. I hope this is a good thing :) Thank you for the nice words.