# Unobtrusive validation works on one controller but not another

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, telerik-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have two different views belonging to two different controllers.  A view the first controller works fine with unobtrusive validation.  The 2nd view does not.  It seems like validation plugin is not running because `$.validator.unobtrusive` is `undefined`.

In the shared _layout file I have the following script tags:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

so why is the 2nd view not working with unobtrusive validation?

### Update

In both cases I am loading the forms via Ajax calls.  I have verified the the main page with the broken validation can support unobtrusive validation for non-ajax loaded forms.

### Update2

I finally got it working, but it's not a permanent fix yet.  The source of the problem is an **editable** Telerik MVC Grid on the same page.  It's somehow deleting/preventing the `$.validator.unobtrusive` from being used in my ajax loads.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will make a difference or not, but are you able to change each line to the following?

```
<script src="@Url.Content('~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js')" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content('~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.min.js')" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content('~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js')" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content('~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js')" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content('~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js')" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is a very MINOR change, but the `"`s in @Url.Contents() have been changed to `'`s. The quotes may be getting crossed at some point.

Comment: I used your suggesting but swapped the single quotes to be on the outside since I want to use double quotes inside for the .net string.  The problem remains

Comment: Have you looked at the answer for this similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321040/unobtrusive-validation-on-dynamically-added-partial-view-not-working

Comment: That doesn't help me because `$.validator.unobtrusive` is undefined

Comment: I believe I may need to see more code to help further, but I did find another posting discussing the undefined issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103160/unobtrusive-client-validation-in-partial-views ...Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah, I saw that before.  The first thing in the source of that function is `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(selector);` so I don't think that will work.

Comment: I've added comments to the original post that pinpoint the root of the problem.